# How much does server location matter when using Cloudflare with 99.7% cache rate?

Tags: performance, caching, digital-ocean, cloudflare

I run a simple Wordpress project which make a large collection of YouTube videos searchable and then displays them as embeds/iframes. It's run on a simple shared hosting at Digital Ocean with Cloudflare and their APO in front.
I am based in Europe as is the server at DO. The majority (90%+) of the traffic comes from the USA/Canada.
The cache rate is about 99.7% as the content (video pages) barely changes.

**My question is:** Would visitors in USA/Canada see a big improvement in load times if I move my server to a NA-based datacenter? Or does Cloudflare and the high cache rate already move my content as close as possible to American/Canadian visitors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main objective of a CDN when caching static content is to move the content closer to your visitors and speeding up the performance as a result.

With a 99.7% cache rate, your users are already downloading content from a Cloudflare datacenter close to them in the majority of the scenarios.

The North American based users would benefit from a NA-based DC only for requests that are a cache `MISS`: in such cases, they would be fetching the content from the Digital Ocean origin in Europe. Based on your numbers this is a very little proportion of your traffic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Seems my intuition isn't wrong. In the future I'll be more mindful of server and audience locations but for now it seems alright!